# Why I can't change notify url with paypal rest api?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

If I create pay-button, in hidden-input was setting "notify_url", but I can't find where is set they in paypal-sdk-php.

Answer (score 0):

the notify url is set in the backend. You have a page with settings, once you create your app. That's where it will be. Paypal doesn't need you to tell it what that URL is every time.

Makes it impossible to hack and change by unauthorised users.